# разработка авторизации на сайте

Tags: php, html, cookie

Делаю авторизацию на учебном сайте. Надо, чтобы пользователь оставался в сети пока не нажмет на кнопку "выход".

Для этого при авторизации пользователя, я сохраняю его id в куке, а при нажатии на "выход" удаляю эту куку.

Мне подсказали, что так делать не хорошо. Если в ручную поменять значение id в куке на другую, мы зайдем на профиль другого пользователя.

Как это лучше реализовать?

Есть идея: сохранять в куке id не в чистом виде, а шифровать его (например с помощью md5).

Comment: Лучше шифровать MD5 (ip + пароль + юезрагент + id(login,email, то что идентифицирует юзера)) и вот это хранить на клиенте. Тут у вас есть проверка на конкретный браузер, проверка на новый пароль, если юзер сменил пароль он уже не зайдет со старыми куками

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете куки или всё таки сессии?

При объявлении сессии генерируется идентификатор и записывается в куки и по нему подымается сессия. Ничто не может гарантировать, что кто-то сможет "увести" Ваш идентификатор и использовать его. Лучше применять дополнительные меры защиты это привязка к ip-адресу и к User-Agent. Но в любом случае это не 100% гарантия.

Что обязательно нужно посоветовать это SSL (https) на сайте.

Comment: сессии же уничтожаются при закрытии браузера. а мне надо, чтобы пользователь оставался в сети пока не нажмет на "выход"

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь (давно не кодил на php), то в настройках сервера можно установить время жизни сессии. Закрытие сессии делается с помощью функции session_destroy(), но если же не применять эту функцию, сессия будет автоматически уничтожена по истечении установленного времени жизни для сессии.  PHP не может узнать закрыл ли человек сайт или нет, он уничтожает сессию через установленный промежуток времени.

Comment: Если я тоже не ошибаюсь, то при смене IP сессия может тоже уничтожиться.

Comment: @CraftPE если делать проверку по IP-адресу то да. Если не делать, то сессия будет уничтожена по истечении установленного времени жизни, даже если поменяется ip адрес.